# How to calculate the average time taken by services from Kibana logs

Tags: spring-boot, kibana

We have a few spring boot microservices which interact over AWS SQS queues and AWS SNS topics.We are using Kibana for our data visualization needs. I want to calculate the time taken for a request which starts from Service A --> Service B --> AWS SNS Topic --> AWS SQS --> Service C. All these services are running on EKS cluster

If i put the start time and end time for each request in the Service A and Service C respectively , is there a way I can generate a dashboard in kibana which will show the average time taken by the end to end requests over a period of time? Is Kibana the right tool for this?

Comment: I think you can pass in a unique id which will be passed over to each of the layers. Log the total time for each service/layer. Then use visualize tab of kibana to aggregate results based on unique id.

Comment: @Smile do u mean like a mdc traceId?

Comment: Yes MDC trace id

Comment: @Smile : I did try the Visualization tab in Kibana. For some other requirement(Count per day) I did create "Vertical Bar" visualizations with Y-axis as "Count" and X-axis as '@timestamp per day'.  However I am when I am trying to get a Visualisation for total time taken  by requests based on grouping by traceId, I am getting confused as to what to seelct as the X-axis variable and Y-axis variable. Should the x axis be over timestamp grouped by trace id? and y axis be percentile?

Comment: Hi, I have your same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a most suitable option for this in AWS.

Take a look at AWS X-Ray, you generate for your a unique ID https://aws.amazon.com/pt/xray/ and you can pass this ID to generate network graphs like this:

[image]

Comment: what I am looking at is more of an aggregator. I don't want to pass ids one by one but want to check the average time taken by all requests within a given time frame

Comment: You can create a log and put this log on an Elasticsearch cluster. This way you would have a dashboard where you can do this.